# Is there a command to start a program after a delay?

Tags: startup, startup-applications

Is there a command to start a program after a delay?

Something like `shutdown 0` for `firefox` where firefox launch after a delay.

I was following [this tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/manage-startup-applications-ubuntu/) where it says adding `sleep 150` adds a delay of 150 seconds before it starts the program. But it doesn't seem to be working. The program never launches on startup after I made this edit.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? I read it as _"start firefox 150 seconds after system startup/boot/login"_ but according to your question's title `sleep 150; firefox` in a command line would do.

Comment: Do you want this at boot/reboot of the computer, or delayed after you run a command (manually)? Or some other way? Please explain.

Comment: @sudodus I think I figured out: according to the tutorial he wants a new entry in _Startup applications_ that starts firefox with a delay of 150 seconds.

Comment: @PerlDuck, Yes, this is what I think too, but let us wait for an answer from Sandeep C. - Firefox and other GUI programs should be started that way. Programs that need not communicate with the desktop (that read from files and write to files) can be started via `crontab` '@reboot'.

Comment: Yes, @PerlDuck identified my requirement correctly. For example, I edited the command to `sleep 120; dropbox start -i` after reading the tutorial. But, Dropbox never launches on startup now. So what is the correct method of implementing this?

Does `bash -c "sleep 10m && dropbox start -i"` work?